# linear regression line with matplotlib gives ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a linear regression line on a scatter plot. I have researched it (for example [Linear regression with matplotlib / numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148207/linear-regression-with-matplotlib)) but my implimentation doesn't work

```
    x = [-6.0, -5.0, -10.0, -5.0, -8.0, -3.0, -6.0, -8.0, -8.0, 7.5, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 7.0, 5.0, 5.0, -8.0, 8.0, 7.0] 
    y = [-7.094043198985176, -6.1018562538660044, -15.511155265492038, -2.7131460277126984, -8.6127363078417609, -3.1575686002528163, -10.246242711042497, -6.4333658386991992, -16.167988119268013, 2.4709555610646134, 4.5492058088492948, 5.5896790992867942, 3.3824425476540005, -1.8140272426684692, -1.5975329456235758, 5.1403915611396904, -4.4469105070935955, 0.51211850576547091, 5.7059436876065952]
    m,b = numpy.polyfit(x,y,1)
    plt.plot(x, y, x, m*x+b) 
    plt.show()
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 464, in <module>
    correlate(trainingSet,trainingSet.trainingTexts)
  File "test.py", line 434, in correlate
    plt.plot(x, y, x, m*x+b)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2458, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3848, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 323, in _grab_ne
xt_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 300, in _plot_ar
gs
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 240, in _xy_from
_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

I have checked that both `x` and `y` are the same length, and they are (19). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is a python `list`, not a `numpy` `array`, so `*` works not the way you expected:

```
>>> m * x
[]
```

This is the working example

```
plt.plot(x, y, x, numpy.array(x) * m +b)
```

Comment: still I'm new to `numpy` and I don't know _why_ `m*x == []` :D

Comment: This is quite interesting.  m is of type `numpy.float64`.  Apparently that type overrides `__mul__` (and `__rmul__`) such that `m*sequence` returns  `int(m)*sequence`.  Had m been a regular python float, an exception would have been raised since sequences can't multiply floats.

Comment: @mgilson, haha, weird indeed, thanks for the info, I'm always forgetting that this language is interpreted and everything is in front of my eyes :)