# Line of best fit in Python for csv data set?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, best-fit-curve

I'm making a very basic plot. I have a csv data set that looks like this:

```
1,280.6
2,280.2
3,276.6
4,279.6
5,277.4
6,279.4
7,274.2
8,278.2
9,276.4
10,279.4
11,274.6
12,276.2
13,274.4
14,277.8
```

and I am plotting it with matplotlib like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter=',',header=None,names=['x','y'])

plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], label='',color=current_palette)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()
```

which gives this:
[a pretty graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvt32.png)

From both my knowledge and from previous answers I've found on here, I know how to calculate line of best fit when I am plotting a given equation or a range or similar. But what would be the best way to find a line of best fit for a given set of data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is too general and needs a lot of information you haven't provided. Curve fitting method really depends on the nature of your data and how the results will be used.

Comment: I'm quite new to this -- could you tell me what kind of information is further needed? I am also just wondering which method would be best so I'm not looking for advice on how to do anything in particular, just examples of how I *could* do it? This isn't for anything serious either so I won't be using the results for anything important. Sorry if I'm not answering this well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear regression with matplotlib / numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148207/linear-regression-with-matplotlib-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding the line of best fit, I would recommend using scipy's [linear regression module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html).

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(df['x'], df['y'])
```

Now that you have the slope and intercept, you can plot the line of best fit.